# How to simulate reflection of people in a 4 meter parabolic mirror to show that they won't appear upside down?

Tags: modeling, rendering, normals

Answers to the Space Exploration SE question [Which Apollo “mystery” was said to be finally solved by a better rendering engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20143/12102) demonstrate that sometimes a correct rendering is the best way to address a problem.

A question I've recently asked in Astronomy SE [Why are these telescope mirror makers not upside down? (Daniel K. Inouye Solar Telescope)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40256/7982) can probably be quickly, convincingly and definitively addressed with a quick mock-up in Blender.

While I've used it in the past it's mostly from the Python scripting size, I have never developed any aptitude mousing my way around even though it looks easy.

So I thought I'd pose this as a related but different question here, and if answers here can also be used *as guidance* to how one might produce an answer to that question, all the better!

I will then give it a try myself, but I'll be slow and if someone beats me to it there, *great!*

The mirror in question has a diameter of 4 meters. It is f/2 meaning the focal length is $f=8$ meters, and [Wikipedia tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_reflector#Theory) that the height of the mirror as a function of radius should be:

$$h_p(r) = \frac{r^2}{4f} $$

This can also be *fairly well approximated* with a sphere of radius $2f$ or 16 meters which can be generated in Blender without an equation, but just for completeness:

$$h_s(r) = 2f - \sqrt{4f^2 - r^2}$$

It's an off-axis paraboloid, but not very much off-axis; just enough so that the secondary is not directly intercepting the sunlight illuminating the primary, in order to reduce diffraction effects.

**Question:** Based on perspective cues and relative sizes in the image (e.g. handrail in front has larger apparent size than people's heads in back): *How would one go about simulating the reflection of these people in a 4 meter parabolic mirror to show that they won't appear upside down?*

---

The linked question in Astronomy SE:

> The new open access Solar Physics article [The Daniel K. Inouye Solar Telescope – Observatory Overview](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11207-020-01736-7) is the first of several papers about the new state-of-the-art solar observatory. For more info see Phys.org's [Solar telescope releases first image of a sunspot](https://phys.org/news/2020-12-solar-telescope-image-sunspot.html)
>
> Figure 4 of the paper is shown below. It is the 4 meter primary mirror viewed at an oblique angle with several people in clean room garb standing behind it.
>
> We can see their reflections in the mirror as well. The geometry is similar to people standing on the opposite side of a reflecting pool.
>
> What struck me is that this differs in an important way; *the people are not upside down!*
>
> 1. Why not exactly?
> 2. Would the people see the camera upside down then?
>
> It looks like the photo was taken from fairly close to the mirror based on the strong perspective scaling from foreground to background objects.
>
> [image: The 4-meter primary mirror (M1) after coating at the AMOS coating facility on Haleakalā.]
>
> > (Figure 4) The 4-meter primary mirror (M1) after coating at the AMOS coating facility on Haleakalā.

Comment: I'm unsure about tagging; are there any tags specific to reproducing a few key geometrical elements of a scene for technical, scientific (or even forensic) purposes without having to be photorealistic? For example, the people's heads could be nicely shaded icosahedrons or a [uv-mapped](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uv) and work just as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mock-up works with Cycles ray-tracing, straightforwardly.

One approach .. You can create the parabolic surface directly, as <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Math Function > Z Math Surface*. Perhaps it's easier to extract the profile from a ZX function, curving in only one direction:

[image]

.. and having deleted all except the vertices: X>=0, Y=0, spin it with a *Screw* modifier.

[image]

Give the disc a 100% metal, pure White, 0 Roughness, mirror-surface.

The right-way-up virtual image is visible only from certain camera angles.. (if you play, you can see the hall-of-mirrors slide from wrong-way-up to right-way-up).

[image]

[image]

Maybe, for perfection, you could calculate the ideal normal of the mirror as a function of object-space XY, and plug that into the shader, to get rid of any artefacts resulting from the linear interpolation between vertices.. but for a demo, that doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: Robin, consider to protect Suzanne. Please add face masks.

Comment: @lemon I checked, (of course) -- there's no record yet of any simian crossover.. but you're right, we should set an example.

Comment: *Sweet!* You can see [this about to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/resAZ.png) to the tallest ones (mentioned [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40256/why-are-these-telescope-mirror-makers-not-upside-down-daniel-k-inouye-solar-t#comment81897_40256)) This looks so easy that I will fire up Blender this weekend and try it, but it won't look anywhere this nice. Please feel free to post an answer there as well, I think that it's *more than competitive* with the existing answer ;-)

Comment: @uhoh Your idea, you go first :) Mine: nothing special, an HDRI environment knocked back to about .25 strength, Sun-lamp for the heroes, a rim for the mirror made from a (modifier-applied) copy of it. I'm sure you can do better.

Comment: (For whatever reason) I will want to script the whole thing, ([1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34609/5334), [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67672/5334), [3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39616/5334), [4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69671/5334)) but I understand "this is my chance" to break into using Blender the normal way. It will take time. maybe this weekend...

Comment: @uhoh .. it is a mathematical subject, that other things could spring from, and ... maybe we share a masochistic pleasure in doing stuff the hard way :D. Whether you take the hard way or not, I look forward to your product / hitches on the journey.

Comment: Okay, it looks like I'm locked in now to learning "against my will" :-)

Comment: Fascinating topic!